# How distribute private program to more than 100 devices?

Tags: xcode, ios

I work in a big company and we have the enterprise count. I build a private iPhone program and successful make a enterprise distribution with ad hoc. So I can delivery the program to 100 devices without the app Store.

But someone say to me that I can delivery to a infinite number of iphone without using the app store. Is it possible?

If not, and if my program will be used to more than 100 iPhones, what can i do? What choice I have?

Comment: [This doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html) doesn't say anything about a 100-device limit

Comment: I think what you need to do is "In-House" Distribution (not "Ad Hoc").  In the Provisioning Portal, under the Distribution section, look at the steps titled "Create and Download a Distribution Provisioning Profile for Enterprise In-House Distribution".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: If you think this is better @FelixSFD, so do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With or without an enterprise account, as an iOS developer you can distribute your app wirelessly via a custom webpage.

Example: http://paddle-battle.com/install/

- How to: http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2010/08/27/wireless-ad-hoc-distribution/
- iOS Developer Library: [http://developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html)

The 100 device limit only affects regular developer accounts.

Comment: You can't install an ad hoc distribution unless your device is added to the provisioning that the app belongs to. If you try to install the app you have just sent the link from any other device not included in the provisioning (like mine, for example), you will download, but won't be able to install it

Comment: @Felipe If the application is distributed with an "In House" provisioning profile, the target devices don't need to be added anywhere and they can install & run just fine.

Comment: @Felipe The Provision profile with the approved devices will be included in the wireless download.

Comment: This work. I used the Beta Builder (http://www.hanchorllc.com/2010/08/24/introducing-ios-beta-builder/) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @FelipeSabino what Dylan said

Answer (score 1):

> But someone say to me that I can
>   delivery to a infinite number of
>   iphone without using the app store. Is
>   it possible?

Yes. The whole point of the enterprise developer program is that it lets large organizations distribute in-house apps without having to go through the App Store. You're not limited in the number of devices that you can distribute to. However, you should read the enterprise program license carefully -- I believe it contains terms that say, essentially, that you're only allowed to distribute within your organization. That is, you can't get an enterprise license and then start distributing your apps publicly.

Comment: Caleb can you do in-house distribution and restrict to only some devices?

Comment: @Muhaye Probably the best way to do what you want is to limit use of the app to users with valid id/password, and have the app check validity from time to time against some server.

Comment: "... you're only allowed to distribute within your organization" - but how about my company's clients? Are they inside of outside this barries?

Comment: @MaciekCzarnik As I understand the enterprise developer agreement, clients aren't part of your organization. But IANAL, and you should really have your legal department review the agreement if you have questions about what's allowed. IMO, it sounds like you need the [Volume Purchase Program for Business](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) rather than the enterprise program.

Comment: @Caleb thanks for your answer - I mean rather proof of concept releases like Ad Hoc, but presumably for more than 100 customers

Comment: @MaciekCzarnik Again, read the agreement. I don't see any language in there that allows what you're asking for.

Comment: Apart from legal problems, if Apple thinks you are going against the terms of the enterprise program, they can revoke the enterprise certificate (and have done so in at least one case), so your employer would be very unhappy.

Comment: Could someone add a link here to this documentation with the enterprise program license stating that you're "only allowed to distribute within your organization". I know I've seen it before, but I can't find where Apple has this documented. Thanks much!

Comment: @Tycon712 As described above, it's in the *iOS Developer Program
Enterprise License Agreement*. I'm not going to link to it because the link will break every time the license is updated (happens several times each year), but if you've subscribed to the program you'll find the agreement in the [Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter). You can also get the basics on the [Enterprise Program page](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).