# Upload iPhone app but keep it private?

Tags: iphone

I have finished developing an iPhone app and my client wants to test it before publishing.

Is it possible to upload the app to the appstore but keep it private? I mean accessable through the app store but only with the developer id?

The client isn't a developer so I can't just send him the code, he won't understand that.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set a release date far in the future so that the app won't be visible in the store and send the client a promo code.  That will allow the client to download and use the app from the store without the app actually being visible in the store.

However  as [ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996644/upload-iphone-app-but-keep-it-private/5996672#5996672) mentions, the best way to go about this would be ad-hoc distribution either by sending the client an ipa that they can sync to their phone through iTunes, or through [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) which is a fantastic service.

Answer (score 3):

You should use something like [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) to distribute an ad-hoc build to them.

Comment: Great suggestion, but an important point is that you don't _need_ TestFlight to distribute ad hoc builds -- you can do it yourself.

Comment: Certainly, but something like TestFlight eliminates a lot of friction for non-technical clients.

Comment: Apple purchased Testflight and shut it down some months ago. You have to use their new internal "Test flight" (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

> I mean accessable through the app
>   store but only with the developer id?

No. Do an ad hoc distribution build and give that to your client. They can install it by dropping it into iTunes and syncing. Or, [this recent SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5916827/643383) gives some pointers that'll help you distribute directly to your client's phone wirelessly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload to the app store but keep it private. The way to distribute apps to phones is to get the UUID of the phone and build a ".ipa" file specifically for those phone(s). You can then email the files to the testers.

There are a couple of apps that do the distribution for you -- TestFlightApp is one, diawi is another.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, upload your app in iTunesConnect.

Add your client as a team member in the Users & Roles module.

Upload a build through Xcode.

Wait about 5 minutes for "processing" to finish.

Open the My Apps module in iTunesConnect.

Select your app.

Select "Prelease"

Select the build you uploaded.

Enter details for "What's new" -- you MUST enter a non-empty string or your client will not receive a download link.

Click save.

Return to the Prelease tab.

Enable the toggle switch for Testflight Beta build for that app.

Your client receives an email with an install. It is valid for 30 days.