# Distribution of MonoTouch App to My Specific Users Only an Users May be Greather Than 10000

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

My **MonoTouch App is developed** now I wanted to distribute this monotouch app to my **specific users only** so mean while on googling I get one more facility given by apple ie B2B so please give any ideas which is the most suitable and affordable for me.
App Users that use my app are having more than >10,000 thousands. So which way I used to distribute my app to my Users Only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The B2B distribution means, that you develop an app for a company which **is located in US** and **participates in Apple Volume Purchase Program.** Is that right for your more than 10000 users?

If you want to distribute your app for a specific user group, you should create a free login process for your app and upload it for AppStore to public use. In this case, you can give your users a registration code (it can be downloadable in a specific webpage, or you can send it e-email, etc...). After it, you should distribute your specific app on app-store.

Or you can create internal distribution with your enterprise developer account, but it is bound a company registered with 1000 emploies. After it, you can distribute iOS apps for internal usage without Apple review and AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) ($299/year) license, you'll could publish in-house iOS apps to only your users.

I beleave that there are no device limits in that program.

Please read some notes in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5996747/548395) response.

Comment: Note that "your users" have to be part of your company. You may not distribute towards users that are not considered part of your company using the enterprise developer program. Apple is very strict on that matter and in case of violation of these terms, your account may immediately closed without refund.

Comment: Yes. If srk's users are not staff of one company, it is impossible to use enterprise program. If so, server-side user checking should be implemented. I.e. app will be published in App Store as any other app, it will have "demo" account, which could not do too much. Srk's should be authenticated on a server-side of app to use all of it's features. One must know that when you publish such app, you should provide full functional account to Apple reviewers/testers (App -> Exactly app version -> Version Information -> Details -> Review Notes (Optional))

Comment: Do the iOS devices need to be managed by the company, or owned by the company? Or could these be BYOD devices?