# How do i do an open beta with my iOS app?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I'm currently developing an app for the iOS app store and i want to have it run through an open beta before i release it to the app store. Ideally, i would want anybody to be able to download the app as long as they have the right permissions (some sort of an app key maybe).

What is the best way to achieve an open beta for an iOS app? Ideally i don't want to get an "in house" distribution provided by apples enterprise accounts.

I have seen this ([How distribute private program to more than 100 devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916827/how-distribute-private-program-to-more-than-100-devices)) on wireless ad-hoc distribution but i want more concrete information on the same. Specifically:

- What is the dev account i need to get with apple to distribute to an open beta.
- Best way to distribute to an open beta.
- Restrictions (if any) on the device number, type of devices (jailbroken or otherwise)
- How do i provision (and the kind of distribution profile i need to get) my apps.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app distribution, not programming.

Comment: But, from the [faq], `practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development` are on topic.

Comment: Since this has been marked has on hold can i know what other information i need to provide so that i can get this resolved? I think doing an open beta (which would be easy on most other mobile platforms) is slightly tricky on iOS and would like to find a reasonable solution for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lukas' answer cover Enterprise Distribution pretty well, so I'll outline the option of general release, restricted user base.

---

Firstly I'd like to point out, it seems Apple is of the mind that beta versions shouldn't be allowed, for example in the [Apple Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) (login required) it states:

> **2.9**
>      Apps that are "beta", "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected

That being said, I've seen a few apps which are beta versions released on the store, so this rule may be a bit more lax than some of the others.

---

I'd consider releasing the app on the normal app store following the same pattern as any other application with a few changes:

- Phrasing: For Apple's benefit, you're releasing a full app, not a beta, it's the users that are restricted, not the app's features.
- Add a login form to the front of the app to allow only specific users to use the app.
- Add the ability to create a beta account. (And limit the number of users as you see fit)
- Consider releasing the app in a limited number of countries to get an idea of your user base without exposing your entire market to a potentially flawed app.

Comment: When you say normal ap store you mean the iTunes store right?
And im assuming id need to get an enterprise account to do this? 
This way everyone can download the app, but people who can use the app would be restricted to those who have access to the beta, am i correct?

Comment: Yes, the normal app store. No, no enterprise account required. How are you selecting your beta users?

Comment: Well i want to do an open beta. Where a potential beta user has to request access to use the app. Apart from having a login, i was thinking of something on the lines of an app key which the beta user has to input to use the app. And the app key will be provided by me once the beta user requests access for the app..

Comment: That's a similar technique to login.. that would work

Answer (score 2):

Enterprises can obtain enterprise certificates which allow them to sign applications so that they can be deployed on any iOS device (no Jailbreak required) just like the app was downloaded from the app store.
However enterprises need to commit that they wont distribute these apps outside of their organization.
For more infomration have a look at Apples iOS Developer Enterprise Program: https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html

There is no other way to distribute apps without publishing to the App store.

Answer (score 0):

Check out TestFlight http://testflightapp.com

You upload your IPA file then invite testers.

Comment: I have been using TF but i have a limit of a 100 devices, im not sure how TF would work with an enterprise distribution, any ideas on that?

Comment: @Sagar I check out their FAQ, it looks like they're working on enterprise distribution, but it's not a thing yet and I doubt it will be any time soon. Good luck on your search :)

Comment: Thanks, will look at what TF are working on!